# jquery ui dialog: possible to create a list element on close?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When I close the dialog, I want a list element to be made on the fly.  When the list element is clicked, the dialog is opened again.  Is this possible?

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    close: function() {
        var e = $(this).parent().find('.ui-dialog-title').text();
    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    $('li',
        {
        class: id,
        value: e,
        click: function(){
        $('#'+id).dialog('open');
            }
    }).appendTo('#aULelement');
    },
    open: function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        if ($('.'+id).length){
            $('.'+id).remove();
        }
    }
});
```

As of now, this code does not build a list item but returns no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.  You need to use `<li/>` and `text` or `html` instead of `value`:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    close: function() {
        var e = $(this).parent().find('.ui-dialog-title').text();
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $('<li/>', {
            class: id,
            text: e,
            click: function() {
                $('#' + id).dialog('open');
            }
        }).appendTo('#aULelement');
    },
    open: function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        if ($('.' + id).length) {
            $('.' + id).remove();
        }
    }
});
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/BGLxW/

Comment: Jeff B, that did the trick- thanks!  I own the book jQuery in Action and I simply could not find your info in it.  Any idea of what resource taught you the <li/> (does this count as a selector?) and text properties?  I see that jsfiddle is an excellent way to test code- again, highly appreciated.

Comment: Just self taught.  I play with jsfiddle a lot, which helps.  You can experiment there until it works and it is a much faster dev cycle than making updates to a site, and generally a bit faster than working locally.

Comment: To answer your question about `<li/>`, it's not a selector.  When you provide a selector, jQuery will look for an existing element (or elements) that matches your selector.  In this case, you are providing html, so jQuery knows to create a new element.  Similarly, you can do something like `$('#myDiv').append('<div id="newDiv">Any html can go here</div>');`.

Comment: P.S., creating an element with object data (i.e. `{class: id,...}`) is relatively new (1.4 I believe), so your book may not have it if it is printed before 2010.

Comment: I see that <li/> is not standard HTML so I figured this is merely some odd way of telling jQuery to make an element and with a closing tag.  Object data is in the book (covers 1.4) however, it merely glosses over this twice I've found and does not show the properties of 'class' and 'text' so I was making a stab in the dark originally, as online docs of this are sparse I find.  Interesting note: you must actually have some quotes around 'class' in order for IE8 not barf with an error however, most other properties don't seem to require this.

Comment: `<li/>` is just a shortcut for `<li></li>`.  Both work the same in this context.